# Exceptionally low CPU performance [22.04.2 LTS]

Tags: drivers, kernel, 22.04, cpu, gnuradio

got a new machine to work with GNUradio (all dependencies met, worked on a few other machines before just fine), yet it runs so slow that it's impossible to work with (especially FFTs). Did CPU benchmarks with 'hardinfo', and some of its benchmarks (blowfish, fibonacci,N-Queens, FFT) show minimal results, so I suspect some package and/or driver issue.

I'm on
`5.19.0-46-generic`

and hwinfo output for the CPU:

```
                       11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz, 3622 MHz
                       11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz, 3825 MHz
                       11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz, 2800 MHz
                       11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz, 4225 MHz
                       11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz, 4208 MHz
                       11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz, 3911 MHz
                       11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz, 3942 MHz
                       11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz, 4093 MHz
```

Governor is set to performance via cpupower-gui, driver is intel_pstate.

Currently installed packages regarding the system are

````
linux-firmware/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,now 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.14 all [installed,automatic]
linux-generic-hwe-20.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0.76.74 amd64 [installed]
linux-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.19.0.46.47~22.04.21 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0.76.74 amd64 [installed]
linux-headers-5.15.0-76-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-76.83 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-5.15.0-76/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-76.83 all [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-5.19.0-35-generic/now 5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-headers-5.19.0-46-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.19.0.46.47~22.04.21 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0.76.74 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-35/now 5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1 all [installed,local]
linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-46/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
linux-hwe-5.19-tools-5.19.0-46/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.15.0-76-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-76.83 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic/now 5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.19.0.46.47~22.04.21 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0.76.74 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-libc-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-76.83 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-5.15.0-76-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-76.83 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-5.19.0-35-generic/now 5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-modules-5.19.0-46-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-76-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-76.83 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-35-generic/now 5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-46-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-sound-base/jammy,jammy,now 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7 all [installed,automatic]
linux-tools-5.19.0-46-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1 amd64 [installed]
linux-tools-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-76.83 all [installed]```


So yeah, if anyone got ideas as to what might be the cause, it'd be much appreciated.
````

Comment: Read `man top ps`. Run `top`. Run `ps -efl`.

Comment: Is your system throttling back due to thermal and/or power limits? Use `turbostat` to show information while your system executes your FFTs. I suggest similar to `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 10`